# How to extract a single character from the elements in vector<char*>?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am trying to extract a single element from a string literal included a list composed of string literals. I used VS Code.

First, I used pointer to make the array of string literals and succeeded in the extracting particular single character in C.

I ran following code to check this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
  char* list[]={"abc","def","ghi"};
  printf("%c\n",list[1][1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Then, I tried to use vector instead of array to make the list consists of string literals in C++.

I ran following code but failed:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<const char*> list;
  list = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    const char* temp = list[i];
    cout<<temp[3]<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I ran the code above, just blank was displayed:

I also tried changing `const char*` to `char*`, but it didn't worked well, too.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<char*> list;
  list = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    char* temp = list[i];
    cout<<temp[3]<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why my codes does not work well to extract the single character included the element of `list`.
Could you please tell me the reason why my didn't work well?

I appreciate if you could help me.

**Notations**

Based on the comments, I revised my code. I changed `char*` to `string` as following:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<string> list;
  list = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    string temp = list[i];
    cout<<temp[3]<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, the output is also blank as well.

Comment: you cannot modify a string literal. A stirng literal is the thing you write in your code. Your vector contains pointers to c-strings it does not contain string literals. Use a `std::vector<std::string>` and most of your problems will be gone

Comment: What do you expect that `cout<<temp[3]<<endl;` will print? e.g., what's index 3 of `"abc"`?

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: You have different test cases. `list[1][1]` works, but `list[1][3]` does not. No difference for the vector.

Comment: `temp[3]` is the terminating  null character. It is usually printed as nothing at all. Why did you change from `1` in the working version to `3` and expect the same behaviour?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you for your answer. I changed ```char*``` to ```string```, but it didn't work well. I attached my revised code in the question. Could you please tell me the reason why my revised code didn't work well? Thank you.

Comment: please do not change the question after you received answer(s). If you want to ask a different question about different code you can open a new question

Comment: Why `temp[3]`? That's the real issue. In your previous code you had `list[...][1]`. Why change to `[3]` here? Try `temp[1]` instead.

Comment: @mch I wanted to print one of the single character in ```"abc"```. After one answer, I found iterator should not be 3, but should be either 0, 1, or 2. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @XYJ iterator -> index. I not trying to nit pick, but iterators are something else.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you also for your suggestion to "using namespace std;". It was not until you told me that I know this was a bad practice. I'll try to be careful not to write so from now on.

Comment: @BoP Thank you for your comment. I tested ```list[1][1]``` and successfully, the output is ```e```.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you for your suggestion. I just put a random number there, but I didn't notice that ```3``` is out of range when I wrote the code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you for your advice. I'm sorry that I changed my question after receiving commnets and answer. Actually, I thought my new problem is still related to this question so I added my new trial inspired by comments. In this case, where should I discuss this? I did also considering make a comment but I thought it is not use to attach codes in comment.

Comment: @john Thank you for your suggestion. I haven't noticed that is the reason why I failed. I tried ```temp[1]``` or ```temp[2]``` and it worked well. I feel it is very difficult to find my easy mistakes.

Comment: @XYJ Attention to detail is an important quality to be a programmer. It comes with experience.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have realize that the reason why I should not use ```#Include <bits/stdc++.h>``` after reading the link you gave me. However, I'm not sure what should I use instead of ```using namespace std;``` in the private file (e.g. ```*.cpp```). I think in the [link you gave me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), it mainly focus on using in header files. Actually, I have not completely understand the meaning of ```using namespace ***```, but I would be grateful if you could give me some advice.

Answer (score 3):

`temp[3]` is null character.
the literal "abc" means the array `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`.

Change

```
cout<<temp[3]<<endl;
```

To

```
cout<<temp[2]<<endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I revised my code based on your answer and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `temp[3]` but `"abc"` means an array of size 4 as follows:

`{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`

Where `'\0'` represents the termination of the string. So `temp[3]` is same as `'\0'`.

Please use `temp[2]` instead to access the last character of the string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had just put a random number ```3```, and I couldn't notice this mistake by myself. After revising, it worked well.